Einstein Next Best Action not working when logged in as a community user
I have set up Einstein NBA to suggest recommendations when a case closes in Salesforce. I have the Einstein for Service Unlimited user license for NBA and have assigned the necessary permission sets to the community user. Additionally, I have ensured that the community user can run flows.
When testing in preview mode in Experience Cloud, Einstein NBA functions correctly. When a case is created with a status of Closed, it shows the Einstein Next Best Action Recommendation. However, when logging in as a Customer Community Plus user, the functionality does not work. I am using a person account to log into the community, but I do not believe this should be causing any issues.
Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on why Einstein NBA is not working for Customer Community Plus users in Salesforce Experience Cloud? I have been troubleshooting for many hours and couldn't find any solutions. Thank you.

After wasting so many hours troubleshooting this issue, I finally found that Flow Builder is not supported currently in the Suggested Actions component in experience cloud and is an existing issue.
Here is the issue link: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000xGGQ0/suggested-actions-component-in-experience-cloud-is-not-displayed-for-community-users-when-the-recommendation-source-is-flow-builderComment
